# How to access component methods from “outside” in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Why can’t I access the component methods from “outside” in ReactJS? Why is it not possible and is there any way to solve it?

Consider the code:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var child = <Child />;
        return (
            <div>
                {child.someMethod()} // expect "bar", got a "not a function" error.
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                foo
            </div>
        );
    },
    someMethod: function() {
        return 'bar';
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<Parent />, document.body);
```

Comment: Maybe you need `Pubsub` ?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

React provides an interface for what you are trying to do via the [`ref` attribute](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). Assign a component a `ref`, and its `current` attribute will be your custom component:

```js
class Parent extends React.Class {
    constructor(props) {
        this._child = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this._child.current.someMethod()); // Prints 'bar'
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child ref={this._child} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Note**: This will only work if the child component is declared as a class, as per documentation found here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-class-component

**Update 2019-04-01:** *Changed example to use a class and [`createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) per latest React docs.*

**Update 2016-09-19:** *Changed example to use ref callback per guidance from [the `ref` String attribute](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute) docs.*

Comment: So, the only way to communicate between two child components would be with both having refs and going through a proxy method on the common parent?

Comment: React encourages data-driven components. Let one child call a callback that changes data in its ancestor, and when that data changes the other child will get new `props` and re-render appropriately.

Comment: @RossAllen, haha yes, you would have had to remove the semicolon too in that case.

Comment: @HussienK I prefer to use a block if the function should have no return value so intent is obvious to the next developer who reads the code. Changing that to `{(child) => this._child = child}` would create a Function that always returned `true`, but that value is not used by React's `ref` attribute.

Answer (score 41):

If you want to call functions on components from outside React, you can call them on the return value of renderComponent:

```
var Child = React.createClass({…});
var myChild = React.renderComponent(Child);
myChild.someMethod();
```

The only way to get a handle to a React Component instance outside of React is by storing the return value of React.renderComponent. [Source](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html).

Comment: actually it works for react16. ReactDOM render method returns a reference to the component (or returns null for stateless components).

Answer (score 38):

Alternatively, if the method on Child is truly static (not a product of current props, state) you can define it on `statics` and then access it as you would a static class method. For example:

```
var Child = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    someMethod: function() {
      return 'bar';
    }
  },
  // ...
});

console.log(Child.someMethod()) // bar
```

Comment: Source for this is [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html).

Answer (score 10):

As of React 16.3  `React.createRef` can be used, (use `ref.current` to access)

```
var ref = React.createRef()

var parent = (
  <div>
    <Child ref={ref} />
    <button onClick={e=>console.log(ref.current)}
  </div>
);

React.renderComponent(parent, document.body)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since React 0.12 the API is [slightly changed](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/28/react-v0.12.html#new-terminology-amp-updated-apis). The valid code to initialize myChild would be the following:

```
var Child = React.createClass({…});
var myChild = React.render(React.createElement(Child, {}), mountNode);
myChild.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 2):

You **could** also do it like this, not sure if it's a good plan :D

```
class Parent extends Component {
  handleClick() {
    if (this._getAlert !== null) {
      this._getAlert()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child>
        {(getAlert, childScope) => (
          <span> {!this._getAlert ? this._getAlert = getAlert.bind(childScope) : null}</span>
        )}
        </Child>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}> Click me</button>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }

class Child extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { count: 0 }
  }

  getAlert() {
    alert(`Child function called state: ${this.state.count}`);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.getAlert, this)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some of the comments, `ReactDOM.render` no longer returns the component instance.  You can pass a `ref` callback in when rendering the root of the component to get the instance, like so:

```
// React code (jsx)
function MyWidget(el, refCb) {
    ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent ref={refCb} />, el);
}
export default MyWidget;
```

and:

```
// vanilla javascript code
var global_widget_instance;

MyApp.MyWidget(document.getElementById('my_container'), function(widget) {
    global_widget_instance = widget;
});

global_widget_instance.myCoolMethod();
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way so easy:

function outside:

```
function funx(functionEvents, params) {
  console.log("events of funx function: ", functionEvents);
  console.log("this of component: ", this);
  console.log("params: ", params);
  thisFunction.persist();
}
```

Bind it:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.funxBinded = funx.bind(this);
  }
}
```

Please see complete tutorial here: [How to use "this" of a React Component from outside?](https://www.4codev.com/react/how-to-use-this-of-a-react-component-from-outside-idpx3498006954402271589.html)