# Call a function on a ReactJs component class object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following ReactJs class:

```
var Linker = React.createClass({
  foo: function(){
    console.log('foo')
  },

  render: function(){
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
});
```

Now I want to call the foo() function from the outside:

```
Linker.foo();
```

But it throws:

```
app.js:4654 Uncaught TypeError: Linker.foo is not a function
```

Can anyone tell me how to call the foo() method?

Reason: I have to use an older version of react-router where I need an old ES5 class with some mixins to transition to a different route. My Plan is to let the Linker class do the transition while my main class is ES6.

Comment: Why Linker can't be accesed with [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)?

You  should direct call constructor of React$Element never

Comment: @Yozi Yes, found that out too, which works very nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need access to the function without any context, then you can find it directly on the prototype property for `Linker`.

```
Linker.prototype.foo();
```

Comment: That didn't work in my case because without context, he can't find the router. But it seems to work when you don't need the context.

Comment: No worries. You might want to consider editing and re-wording the question before marking the accepted answer, as in the example you were looking for the method on the factory instance, not the component instance.

Comment: I edited the question and marked your answer as the correct one because it is indeed the right answer of my question, even if it doesn't work for me because I need the context.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24848228/3877081

I had to render the Linker component and can access it through refs.