# Popup always open in the marker

Tags: react-leaflet

Is there any way the popup always stays open and does not need to click on it to open?

- [Expected behaviour](https://monosnap.com/file/mPkuSTmPAfwxTxY99YQVA5m96Zolow.png)
- [Actual behavior](http://take.ms/cUej0)

Comment: Can you add an example of what you already have? More specifically what kind of data, and what components you are using.

Comment: When you say "stay open", do you mean that when the map loads the popup is already open?

Comment: Also, you posted the same screenshot for both links :P

Comment: Yes @EricPalakovichCarr.

Thks, i changed the image lol

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you can do is to make your own Marker class from the react-leaflet marker, and then call the leaflet function openPopup() on the leaflet object after it has been mounted.

```
// Create your own class, extending from the Marker class.
class ExtendedMarker extends Marker {
    componentDidMount() {
        // Call the Marker class componentDidMount (to make sure everything behaves as normal)
        super.componentDidMount();

       // Access the marker element and open the popup.
      this.leafletElement.openPopup();
    }
}
```

This will make the popup open once the component has been mounted, and will also behave like a normal popup afterwards, ie. on close/open.

I threw together this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrcoq72t/) that shows the same code together with the basic example.

Comment: nice one. in case one is willing to keep the popup open after the marker has been moved, following code has to be added:

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        super.componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState);
      this.leafletElement.openPopup();
    }

Comment: Hi, I did as you suggested but I get en error: TypeError: Marker is not a constructor. Why?

Answer (score 20):

With the introduction of `react-leaflet version 2` which brings breaking changes in regard of [creating custom components](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/custom-components.html), it is no longer supported *to extend components via inheritance* (refer [this thread](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/506) for a more details)

In fact [React official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) also recommends to use composition instead of inheritance:

> At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t
>   found any use cases where we would recommend creating component
>   inheritance hierarchies.
>
> Props and composition give you all the flexibility you need to
>   customize a component’s look and behavior in an explicit and safe way.
>   Remember that components may accept arbitrary props, including
>   primitive values, React elements, or functions.

The following example demonstrates how to extend marker component in order to keep popup open once the marker is displayed:

```
const MyMarker = props => {

  const initMarker = ref => {
    if (ref) {
      ref.leafletElement.openPopup()
    }
  }

  return <Marker ref={initMarker} {...props}/>
}
```

Explanation:

get access to native leaflet marker object (`leafletElement`) and open popup via [`Marker.openPopup` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-openpopup)

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-awtgn6)

Comment: can be shorten to `const initMarker = ref => { ref?.leafletElement.openPopup() }`. but nice solution since it is working with functional components

Answer (score 4):

You can use permanent [tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171437/auto-open-markers-popup-on-react-leaflet-map?rq=1), or React provides refs for this type of thing... you can do this:

https://jsfiddle.net/jrcoq72t/121/

```
const React = window.React
const { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } = window.ReactLeaflet

class SimpleExample extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      lat: 51.505,
      lng: -0.09,
      zoom: 13
    }
  }

  openPopup (marker) {
    if (marker && marker.leafletElement) {
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        marker.leafletElement.openPopup()
      })
    }
  }

  render () {
    const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng]
    return (
      <Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
        <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
        <Marker position={position} ref={this.openPopup}>
          <Popup>
            <span>
              A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </span>
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </Map>
    )
  }
}

window.ReactDOM.render(<SimpleExample />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

References:

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

[React.js - access to component methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841855/react-js-access-to-component-methods)

[Auto open markers popup on react-leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171437/auto-open-markers-popup-on-react-leaflet-map?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

The above no longer works with react-leaflet version 3. In your custom marker component, to get a reference to the leaflet element you should now use `useRef()` and then open up the popup in `useEffect()` once the component is mounted.

```
const MyMarker = (props) => {
  const leafletRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    leafletRef.current.openPopup();
  },[])
  return <Marker ref={leafletRef} {...props} />
}
```

Comment: This example lead to this kind of error, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'openPopup' of undefined`. Do  you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For the new react-leaflet v4 you will need to do some changes

```js
   const CustomMarker = ({ isActive, data, map }) => {
                  const [refReady, setRefReady] = useState(false);
                  let popupRef = useRef();
                
                  useEffect(() => {
                    if (refReady && isActive) {
                      map.openPopup(popupRef);
                    }
                  }, [isActive, refReady, map]);
                
                  return (
                    <Marker position={data.position}>
                      <Popup
                        ref={(r) => {
                          popupRef = r;
                          setRefReady(true);
                        }}
                      >
                        {data.title}
                      </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                  );
                };
```

And then use `MapContainer` like this

```js
const MapComponent = () => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div>
      <MapContainer
        ref={setMap}
        center={[45.34416, 15.49005]}
        zoom={15}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
      >
        <CustomMarker
          isActive
          map={map}
          data={{
            position: [45.34416, 15.49005],
            title: "Text displayed in popup",
          }}
        />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: you should use the `useMap` hook provided by `react-leaflet`.
That way you won't need to pass `map` as a prop

Answer (score 0):

#### Edited

Notice that my old solution would try to open the popup every time it renders.
Found another solution that fit my needs to open it when the position changed. Notice that I look at position.lat, position.lng since it will think it always changes if you pass on the object.

And yes it is not perfect typescript but it is the best solution I could come up with.

```js
const CustomMarker: React.FC<CustomMarkerProps> = ({ position, children }) => {
  const map = useMap();

  const markerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      // @ts-ignore
      if (markerRef.current !== null && !markerRef.current.isPopupOpen()) {
        // @ts-ignore
        markerRef.current.openPopup();
      }
    } catch (error) {}
  }, [position.lat, position.lng]);

  return (
    <Marker ref={markerRef} position={position}>
      <Popup>{children}</Popup>
    </Marker>
  );
};

export default CustomMarker;
```

##### Old solution

Could not get it to work using `useRef` and `useEffect`. However, got it to work with calling `openPopup()` directly from the ref.

```js
import { LatLngLiteral, Marker as LMarker } from "leaflet";
import React from "react";
import { Marker } from "react-leaflet";

export interface CustomMarkerProps {
  position: LatLngLiteral;
  open?: boolean;
}
const CustomMarker: React.FC<CustomMarkerProps> = ({
  position,
  open = false,
  children,
}) => {
  const initMarker = (ref: LMarker<any> | null) => {
    if (ref && open) {
      ref.openPopup();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Marker ref={initMarker} position={position}>
      {children}
    </Marker>
  );
};

export default CustomMarker;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the popup once the marker is added to the map:

```js
import { Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

function MyMarker() {
    const position = [41.0, 2.11];

    function openPopup(e) {
        e.target.openPopup();
    }

    return (
        <Marker position={position} eventHandlers={{ add: openPopup }}>
            <Popup closeButton={false} autoClose={false} closeOnClick={false}>
                {/* Content of your popup... */}
            </Popup>
        </Marker>
    )
}
```

This will additionally prevent the popup from closing. Works with react-leaflet 4.2.1.