# Super expression must either be null or a function (Custom Marker)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I'm creating an application where the user can add markers to specific locations on the map just by clicking on the map itself. To this end, I'm using react-leaflet to generate the map and its functionalities. This works perfectly, but I want the popup associated with the marker to be open on creation, and I can't seem to achieve that.

I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730152/popup-always-open-in-the-marker) to get this functionality, and import the extended marker to my map. But alas, the following error appears:

```
Super expression must either be null or a function
at _inherits (Marker.js:21)
at eval (Marker.js:30)
at eval (Marker.js?6e37:11)
at Module../src/utils/components/Marker.js (main.js:11547)
```

This bothers me a lot, mainly because I can't seem to find a specific answer regarding this error when extending the marker class. Here's my extended marker implementation (couldn't be simpler):

```
import { Marker } from 'react-leaflet';

class ExtendedMarker extends Marker {

  componentDidMount() {
    // Call the Marker class componentDidMount (to make sure everything behaves as normal)
    super.componentDidMount();

    // Access the marker element and open the popup.
    this.leafletElement.openPopup();
  }

}

export default ExtendedMarker;
```

And this is where I import it:

```
import ExtendedMarker from '../../../utils/components/Marker';

...

createMarker = (key, lat, lng) => {
  const _lat = round(lat, this.DECIMAL_PLACES);
  const _lng = round(lng, this.DECIMAL_PLACES);
  return (
    <ExtendedMarker key={key} id={key} position={[_lat, _lng]}>
      <Popup className={`${styles.popup}`}>
        <Form>
          ...
        </Form>
      </Popup>
    </ExtendedMarker>
  )
}
```

Here are the versions I'm using:

```
"react-leaflet": "^2.1.2",
"react": "^16.6.1"
```

Any tips?

Thanks,
Gil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [React official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) suggests to prefer composition over inheritance:

> At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t
>   found any use cases where we would recommend creating component
>   inheritance hierarchies.
>
> Props and composition give you all the flexibility you need to
>   customize a component’s look and behavior in an explicit and safe way.
>   Remember that components may accept arbitrary props, including
>   primitive values, React elements, or functions.

i would suggest the following marker component which demonstrates how to *open a popup on marker creation*:

```
const ExtendedMarker = props => {

  const openPopup = marker => {
    if (marker) marker.leafletElement.openPopup();
  };

  return (
    <Marker ref={el => openPopup(el)} {...props}/>
  );
};
```

A [*callback function*](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) is used to access `Leaflet Marker` via `marker.leafletElement`

[Here is a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/34l1q8x951) for your reference

Comment: That made sense, I was looking at this from another point of view. It worked, thank you so much.

Comment: This is a great answer in that it points you in the right direction. It does not explain why you get that error though. That error happens because the author of `react-leaflet` published v2 of his library and completely changed the way extending components works for most components. For a more in depth read on why exactly you get that error check out this github issue: https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/506