# React.js Update Table from Mongo DB After Add New Row

Tags: javascript, java, spring, reactjs, typescript

I have two components that connect main components. Like this:

- Main (Parent)

  - GridView (Child - Table)
  - AddConnectionView (Child - Add Operations)

I can save data successfully by using AddConnectionView Class. I want to update the table in GridView after clicking the save button in AddConnectionView. I think that I'm confused for that since how can I use shouldComponentUpdate function or what I can do or solve this problem.

Please help me. Thank you!

This is my code:

**MainView.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import {GridView} from "./gridView.tsx";
import {AddConnectionView} from "./addConnectionView.tsx";


export class MainSettingsView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context: any) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {clickedbtnNewConnection:false}
    }


    btnNewConnection = () => {
        this.setState({clickedbtnNewConnection:true});
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <form className="ui form">
                <div className="field">
                    <button type="button" className="ui orange button " onClick={this.btnNewConnection}>

                        <i className="plus icon"></i>
                        Yeni Bağlantı Ekle
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="field">
                    <GridView/>
                </div>
                <div className="field">
                    <AddConnectionView clickedBtnNewConnection={this.state.clickedbtnNewConnection} />
                </div>
            </form>


        )}
}
```

**GridView**

```
import * as React from "react";
import {PrivateConnection} from "../../Connection";
import {PrivateConnectionStates} from "../../ConnectionInterfaces";



export class GridView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context: any) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {connectionList:[] } as PrivateConnectionStates;

        this.getAllConnection();

    }

    public getAllConnection(event:any):void{
        fetch('/PrivateConnectionService/findAll',
            {
                method: 'GET',
                credentials: 'include',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then((response) => {
            var contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
            if (contentType && contentType.indexOf("application/json") !== -1) {
                return response.json().then( (json) => {
                    // process your JSON further
                    this.setState({
                        connectionList: [...json] as Array<PrivateConnection>
                    } as PrivateConnectionStates);
                    console.log(this.state.connectionList);

                });
            } else {
                console.log("Oops, we haven't got JSON!");
            }
        })
    }


    render() {

        var tableItems = [];
        var size=Object.keys(this.state.connectionList).length;

        for(var i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            tableItems.push(<tr key={i+1}><td>{this.state.connectionList[i].connectionName}</td><td>{this.state.connectionList[i].databaseName}</td><td>{this.state.connectionList[i].host}</td><td>{this.state.connectionList[i].port}</td><td>{this.state.connectionList[i].serviceName}</td><td>{this.state.connectionList[i].username}</td><td>{this.state.connectionList[i].password}</td></tr>);
        }



        return (

            <div>
                <table className="ui selectable teal celled table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr className="center aligned">
                            <th>Connection Name</th>
                            <th>Database</th>
                            <th>Host</th>
                            <th>Port</th>
                            <th>Service Name</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Password</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody className="center aligned">
                    {tableItems}


                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>


        )}
}
```

**AddConnectionView**: There are a button and after click the button, I want to refresh the table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you might want to change your design in order to do this. Maybe you could just put the button in the `MainView`, which would make things easier (just update the `GridView` when the button is used sending a prop or invoking `getAllConnection` with [a ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841855/react-js-access-to-component-methods)).

If you need/want to keep your components the way they are and use only React, you could use a **callback function** defined in your `MainView` to send it as a property to your `AddConnectionView`. Using that method (a function of the MainView Component) in `AddConnectionView` (`onClick`), you could send a prop to the GridView Component or invoke `getAllConnection`. By the way, you should call `getAllConnection` in `componentDidMount` instead of the constructor. You can see how this works [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html).

You could also use [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) or [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) to use one centralized state.