# Is there a way to externally reset a react component to its original state

Tags: reactjs

I am current working with some complex stateful React components I installed through npm. For example, a react-bootstrap-table component. It accept data through its props. But it keeps a lots of states of its own, for example, which row is currently selected. I am adding a button, on clicking I would like to clear all the selected row information. Not having access to any API that can do that, I am wondering if I can totally reset the table component.

Right now I use a wrapper component that render the table based on a flag. It looks like:

```
class wrapper extends React.component{

  render(){
    if(this.props.flag==true) return <React-Table />;
    else return null;
      }
}
```

Now by toggling the flag, I can force a re-render of the table component with its original state.

I am wondering if there is a more straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the `react-boostrap-table` API, it found a method `reset` (see [docs](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#reset)):

> Call reset to clean all the status on the table currently.

```
this.refs.table.reset();  // this.refs.table is a ref for BootstrapTable
```

Answer (score 0):

To give a more general answer,

React does not have a general way to reset a component externally, the component should provide it if it's necessary. There are 2 ways for parent component to communicate with child component, through props, or not frequently, using ref to directly call a child method. Resetting is using the second way.

For react-bootstrap-table, there are reset() and cleanSelected() method you can call. [How to call child component method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841855/react-js-access-to-component-methods)