# React - getting Uncaught TypeError when calling component method from outside

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component like below:

```
var Dog = React.createClass({
  bark: function() {
    alert('bow');
  },

  render: function() {
    return (<div>Dog</div>);
  }
});
```

But when I am trying to call the `bark` method by creating an element of `Dog` like below:

```
var doge = React.createElement(Dog, null);
console.log(doge);
doge.bark();
```

I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: doge.bark is not a function`. But in chrome's console I can see the bark method in `doge` object

[image]

I am a beginner in react. Can anyone explain what is actually going on behind the scenes?

**EDIT:**

Actually I want to know why we can not access a component's method from its element created by `React.createElement` method? Please someone explain this.

Comment: 1) You need to spell Dog, dog and doge consistently throughout the program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access component methods from “outside” in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841855/how-to-access-component-methods-from-outside-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

You need to spell and capitalize dog the same way everywhere so Dog, not dog or doge. Then change your render function to call the bark function as follows:

```
 render: function() {
    return (<div>{this.bark()}</div>);
 }
```

Although I would change the function from sending an Alert to a console.log.

For your last three lines of code, you are trying to treat a react component as an object. Just call bark before the render as such:

```
 render: function() {
    this.bark() /*called function on render*/
    return (<div></div>);
 }
```

Comment: You didn't get my question. My question is that when I am creating an **element** of a **component** by the `React.createElement` method and calling a method of that element it is throwing that error. Why it can not access the method?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841855/react-js-access-to-component-methods