# Change child component in React via ref or prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have a child component. Let's say I want to change its height based on information that the parent has.

If I get a reference to it. I can change it with

```
myChild.changeHeight(newHeight);
```

(see [React.js - access to component methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841855/react-js-access-to-component-methods))

or I could change it with

```
<Child height={newHeight}/>
```

Both could be changed in the render() method. But which one should I use?

Comment: Use a prop, that's the standard way to do it, otherwise it looks like a bad hack

Answer (score 0):

[React team](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) gave few scenarios where we should be using refs.

> There are a few good use cases for refs:
>
> - Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
> - Triggering imperative animations.
> - Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.
>
> Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.

If there is a possibility to do some functionality even without using refs, then go ahead and do it. In your case, as you said, you have a way to do it by passing a prop. It would be better if we use props itself rather than ref.